# How to Reverse a given sentence (string) in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, variable-assignment

Example: if the input was DOGS    LIKE CATS
output- CATS LIKE    DOGS

consider that I have to use only : If-else conditions, while & for loops, Arrays, strings and Functions. NOT strings functions, Pointers & Dynamic memory allocation & structures.
Spaces need to be the same as the example as well.

I tried to do the following but it doesnt work can you help please?

```
void revSent(char str[]){
char temp[100];
int k;
for (i=sentenceSize ; i>0 ; i--)
    for (k=0 ; k<sentenceSize ; k++)
        temp[k]=str[i];

for (k=0 ; k<sentenceSize ; k++)
    if (temp[k]!=' ')
        for (i=k ; i>0 ; i--)
            printf("%c", temp[i]);

}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: +1 for adding homework tag and not trying to lie =]

Comment: hint: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: @superfro: That was done by me...

Comment: @Paul Oh well +1 to you then =]

Comment: C# solution; var result = String.Join(" ", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Split().Reverse());

Comment: Use of the [homework] tag (and other meta tags) is now discouraged, apparently: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions - the poster should instead state that a question is homework-related within the question itself.

Comment: its actually a small part of a huge assignment

Comment: @Ben: did you read my answer about doing this *in place* ? You shouldn't need an additional buffer (temp). Think about how to swap two characters.

Answer (score 9):

It's easy to do this in-place, without any additional data structures:

1. reverse the whole string: `DOGS LIKE CATS` -> `STAC EKIL SGOD`
2. reverse each word in the string: `STAC EKIL SGOD` -> `CATS LIKE
   DOGS`

Hint: you can use the same function for both (1) and (2).

Comment: This is the classic solution from Programming Pearls that I was just about to suggest.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Cool - I didn't know this was in Programming Pearls (an excellent book), but it's a well known solution.

Comment: Hey dude check this idid what yo said but it doesnt work well can you hekp me fix it please?    void revSent(char str[]){
 char temp[100];
 int k;
 for (i=sentenceSize ; i>0 ; i--)
  for (k=0 ; k<sentenceSize ; k++)
   temp[k]=str[i];

 for (k=0 ; k<sentenceSize ; k++)
  if (temp[k]!=' ')
   for (i=k ; i>0 ; i--)
    printf("%c", temp[i]);
   
}

Comment: @Ben: see my comment to your question above - the idea is to do this *in place* using the two step algorithm I described in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could implement the following to arrive at a solution:

1. Separate the sentence into a list of words.
2. Reverse this list.
3. Concat this list together to form the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

If you define a word as a whitespace-delimited token then the following will do:

```
std::vector<std::string> sentence;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(sentence));
std::reverse(sentence.begin(), sentence.end());
```

In essence you want to start with the definition of a word, then place in a container your words, and finally use `std::reverse()` to reverse them.

For an algorithms homework your instructor probably won't be satisfied with this. You want to create a function that splits a sentence into words. You can, of course, work with pointers within the same string -- and that may well be the intent of your instructor, but if that isn't what you must then I personally find working with a container easier.

Comment: Two things. 1. This is homework so it is better to guide than to give. 2. He isn't allowed to use data structures (so vector is not permitted).

Comment: That is a nice response. I think he/she is having a string as input, not a stream.

Comment: i didnt learn stream or "std" yet. i can use only things they taught us.

Comment: @DiegoSevilla If the input is a string then you can use an `istringstream`.

Comment: @NoahRoberts this isn't undercutting anything. I gave an answer in pseduocode, it's just that the language I chose for pseudocode is C++.

Comment: You could use a `std::deque` instead of an `std::vector` and a `std::front_inserter` : no more need for `std::reverse` :p

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a hint: since you can't use data structures you can't directly use Paul or OJ's method.  BUT, recursive function calling would form a stack.

Answer (score 0):

- Break the sentence into words
- In order, push each word onto a stack
- Pop each item off the stack and print out/add to list/write to file/whatever.

Voila!

Comment: Also a nice solution, except he explicitly states he cannot use data structures.

Comment: +1 Paul. I'm stupid for not fully reading the question. I hate it when others do that, so I need to be super hard on myself for doing it. Thanks for pointing it out dude. (Edit: crap, I can't downvote my own post)

Answer (score 0):

who says the STL isn't useful?

Depending on how you do this, there are different ways to attack this.

my way is just:

```
while (original_string isn't empty){    
   take first word  
   prepend to reversed string
}
```

Here's the C++ solution (using [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/), two very useful string functions)

```
    using namespace std;
string word_reverse(string original){
    string reverse_string;
    if (original.find(' ')!=string::npos){
        do{
            int pos=original.find(' ');
            //prepend word
            reverse_string=original.substr(0,pos)+' '+reverse_string;
            //remove word from original,considering the found whitespace
            original=original.substr(pos+1,original.length()-(pos+1));
        }while(original.find(' ')!=string::npos);
        //don't forget the last word!
        return original+' '+reverse_string;
    }
    else{//no whitespace: return original text
        return original;
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant use strings functions... Thanks anyway dude